# UILocalNotification Twice every day

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I want to fire local notification twice everyday like for ex:- morning 7am and evening 6pm everyday so can anyone please help me how can i do that?

unable to set custom time to fire the local notification have looked every where but nothing helpful for fire local notification twice in a day if any help will appreciate graetly

Thanks in advance :)

this is the peace of code i am using local notification but it's not firing at all :(

```
- (void)scheduleNotification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];    
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {       
        NSString *end = @"2013-09-20 11:24:00 +0000";
        NSDate *endDate = [self convertStringToDate:end];
        NSLog(@"end date :%@", endDate);

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = endDate;
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
    [notif release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Got the solution how to set `UILocalNotification` for 7am and 6pm and repeat it daily hope it help who are looking fore same solutions on notification

```
-(void)scheduleNotification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {      
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        [components setHour:7];
        [components setMinute:0];
        NSDate *today7am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = today7am;
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        notif.alertBody = @"Did you forget something?";
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;       
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];


        NSCalendar *calendar2 = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar2 components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        [components2 setHour:18];
        [components2 setMinute:0];
        NSDate *today6pm = [calendar2 dateFromComponents:components2];

        UILocalNotification *notif2 = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif2.fireDate = today6pm;
        notif2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif2.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        notif2.alertBody = @"Did you forget something2?";
        notif2.alertAction = @"Show me2";
        notif2.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif2.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        notif2.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif2];
        [notif2 release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you create the date:

```
NSString *end = @"2013-09-20 11:24:00 +0000";
NSDate *endDate = [self convertStringToDate:end];
NSLog(@"end date :%@", endDate);
```

Here you create a date at `11:24 UTC/GMT` but you tell the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to use the system time zone. Zo the date gets offset to the system time zone.

Just set the [`timeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW1) of the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to `GMT`:

```
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

Then the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will be set to the correct time zone of the system and will not use the offset.

**Another option is to not include the time zone in the date string and set the `NSDateFormatter` to include the system time zone.**
But with the code above it should fire even if the timezone changes.

Set the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW3) of  [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to [`NSDayCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit) to make it repeat every day.

```
notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: i am in GMT 5:30 so used 11:24 for firing notification at 05:54:00

Comment: But keep in mind that people all over the world can use you app and there offset is different to yours. So try to make you code work with any time zone.

Comment: okay i agree but how can i set any fix time for firing the notification? if any working code then that would be great help but with fixed time as i want to set notification for fix time everyday repeat

Comment: My example will work, just create a date with GMT and then set the `timeZone` to GMT.

Comment: date with GMT? how can i create that?

Comment: You already do, when you add the `+0000` to the date, that is the time zone. GMT is `+0000`

Comment: ok but it is still not working i can't see notification on screen :(

Comment: Make sure you app is not excluded form the notification center, make sure you don't call ` [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` any where in your app and make sure the implement the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` in your app delegate. Because if you app is running this gets called and the notification will not be handled by iOS. But you should have gotten this all from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set two notifications, one for the morning, one for evening; both would have the `repeatInteval` property set to `NSDayCalendarUnit`.

Comment: i agree but why this code is not working? and if you have any peace of code that how can fire notification at some particular time then that would be really a great help