# Local Notification issue iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to make local notification that notify user 5 times a day and repeat them daily, 
I have them in a mutable array which object is "hh:mm" which hours and minutes are fixed for GMT+3 town, so I get the current date and find the interval then create a date for the notification
that's the method I implement.
-first applying time zone,
-second if the time before current time so make it for the next day.
-third set local notification for that date.
plz help me

[piece of code](http://pastebin.com/9ijwBy03)

Comment: you simply need to set 5 different different notifications with your desired input timings and set the repeat interval to notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit; this.

Comment: I did, but when the date of the firing notification is before the current time it fires !, so I make it next day.

Comment: it's just because you're testing like that don't worry about it user will get it on time coz they will not going to change the time and all stuff so don't mind this issue.

Comment: it doesn't work, can you show me sample of what do you mean ?

Comment: please take a look at my answer it has some sort of code that i am currently using in one of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the use of this sample code i have schedule the 2 notification one at Morning 7AM and one at Evening 6PM and repeated it daily and it works superfine hope you can find out your solution with the use of this.

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark - Notification Setup
-(void)clearNotification
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}

-(void)scheduleNotification
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [APPDELEGATE.userDefaults valueForKey:@"ParsingResponse"];    

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        [components setHour:7];
        [components setMinute:0];
        NSDate *today7am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = today7am;
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        notif.alertBody = [[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Noti_Morning"];
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Morning", @"key", nil];
        notif.userInfo = infoDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];


        NSCalendar *calendar2 = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDateComponents *components2 = [calendar2 components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        [components2 setHour:18];
        [components2 setMinute:0];
        NSDate *today6pm = [calendar2 dateFromComponents:components2];

        UILocalNotification *notif2 = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif2.fireDate = today6pm;
        notif2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif2.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        notif2.alertBody = [[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Noti_Evening"];
        notif2.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif2.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif2.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        NSDictionary *infoDict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Evening", @"key", nil];
        notif2.userInfo = infoDict2;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif2];
        [notif2 release];
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the same question i asked for my situation and finally after lot of research got the solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/18916631/2695503